# ¿Cómo descargar colección de pdf de FirebaseStorage? ¿Cómo solucionar error 404? y 13010

Tags: java, android, error404, firebase-storage

Sigo un video que explica cómo descargar pdf de FirebaseStorage pero me da error 404, Object does not exist at location. No entiendo mucho porque estoy aprendiendo de a poco y no encuentro como debería ser la ruta para que funcione. Busco explicación al respecto pero no encuentro ejemplos donde pueda descargar PDF de una colección. Mi intención es que seleccione el pdf y luego de verlo se descargue. La primera parte esta lograda pero al descargarme muestra el error. No se como redactar y solucionarlo.
Sigue este tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmXGlv7QEO0&t=801s

Modifiqué el código buscando la compatibilidad de la dirección, modifiqué permisos en Firebasecambie el String pensando que debería ingresar por colección, pero claramente al no entender no distinguir si es un error al guardar en el cel o la dirección para llegar a la colección la falla.

Este código lo implemente viendo el video de youtube. Seguí los pasos.
Ya en Android Studio consegui la primer parte que es armar un listview donde aparecen los pdf en la aplicación. Ahora mediante este código quiero descargarlos al celular.

```
downloapdl2 = findViewById(R.id.downloapdl2);

    downloapdl2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            descarga();
        }
    });
    FirebaseStorage mFirebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference mmFirebaseStorageref = mFirebaseStorage.getReference().child("pdl2");

    mmFirebaseStorageref.child(planificacionNombre).getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {

            pdfView.fromBytes(bytes).load();
        }

    }).addOnFailureListener((e) -> {
        Toast.makeText(VisorPDFActivity.this, "Descarga exitosa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    });

}

public void descarga() {
    storageReference = firebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
     ref = storageReference.child("pdl2");

    ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            String url = uri.toString();
            downloadFile(VisorPDFActivity.this,"",".pdf",DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,url);

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        }
    });
}

public void downloadFile(Context context, String fileName, String fileExtension, String destinationDirectory, String url) {
    DownloadManager downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) context.
            getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, destinationDirectory, fileName + fileExtension);

    downloadmanager.enqueue(request);

    }
}
```

[![  En firebaseStorage cree una carpeta donde se encuentran los pdf y se visualizan en la aplicación. ][1]][1]

Acá comparto el error que marca cuando ejecuto la app en mi celular. No estoy usando la computadora para probar sino el celular.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2stj.png

```
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
Object does not exist at location.
 Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
```

E/StorageException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}

Disculpe la demora. Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Hola. ¿Cuál es el código y cuál es el mensaje de error? Pulsa en [edit] y completa la pregunta. No remitas a vídeos o fuentes externas, es norma del sitio que las preguntas sean autocontenidas.